# PHP and Office 365: Unknown SSL protocol error

Tags: php, ssl, curl, office365

I am trying to use the Office 365 (actually Sharepoint) Files REST API by sending cURL requests from PHP. However I got to following error:

```
Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to mysubdomain-my.sharepoint.com:443
```

I have tried to fiddle with the CURLOPT_SSLVERSION setting, from what I have read either SSL3 (3) or TLS1 (1) settings should be used. I readed also that Officw 365 API have stopped using SSL3.

Other than that I have no clue what to do to solve this. There are very little information about using PHP to connect to Microsoft's APIs.

I am not sure about using mysubdomain.onmicrosoft.com/myapp as resource (in $authenticationRequestBody below). The WebApp-GraphAPI-PHP use a different resource string but according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx something similar to my example should be used.

Here is the source code. Basically it is the [WebApp-GraphAPI-PHP example](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-GraphAPI-PHP) slightly modified:

```
<?php
$TENANT = "MY SUB DOMAIN";
$TENANT_DOMAIN = "$TENANT.onmicrosoft.com";
$APP_ID = "APP ID";
$SECRET = "CLIENT SECRET";
$APP_NAME = "APP NAME";

//Generate the authentication header
$clientSecret = urlencode($SECRET);
// Information about the resource we need access for which in this case is graph.
    $graphId = "https://" . $TENANT_DOMAIN . "/" . $APP_NAME;
$graphPrincipalId = urlencode($graphId);
// Information about the app
$clientPrincipalId = urlencode($APP_ID);

// Construct the body for the STS request
$authenticationRequestBody = 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_secret='.$clientSecret
                           .'&'.'resource='.$graphPrincipalId.'&'.'client_id='.$clientPrincipalId;

//Using curl to post the information to STS and get back the authentication response    
$ch = curl_init();
// set url 
$stsUrl = 'https://login.windows.net/' . $TENANT_DOMAIN . '/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0';        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $stsUrl); 
// Get the response back as a string 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
// Mark as Post request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
// Set the parameters for the request
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $authenticationRequestBody);

// By default, HTTPS does not work with curl.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

// read the output from the post request
$output = curl_exec($ch);         
// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

// decode the response from sts using json decoder
$tokenOutput = json_decode($output);

$authHeader = 'Authorization:' . $tokenOutput->{'token_type'}.' '.$tokenOutput->{'access_token'};

$ch = curl_init();

// Add authorization header, request/response format header( for json) and a header to request content for Update and delete operations.  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($authHeader,  'Accept:application/json;odata=minimalmetadata',
                                           'Content-Type:application/json;odata=minimalmetadata', 'Prefer:return-content'));
// Set the option to recieve the response back as string.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
// By default https does not work for CURL.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$TENANT-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v1.0/me/files/root/children");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo(curl_error($ch));
// close curl resource to free up system resources 
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($output);
?>
```

Comment: Not directly linked to your problem, but don't set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to false, set your CA certificates correctly instead.

Comment: Right :) It was just in the code I copied. I discover that I can just turn this on without any additional problems. It does not fix my error but it is at least little more secure (I hope) now.

Comment: I doubt that this is a problem specifically related to PHP and Sharepoint, but related to interaction of the TLS stacks, i.e. usually OpenSSL with PHP and SChannel with Sharepoint. There might be lot of problems in this area like incompatible protocol versions, missing SNI extension, no common ciphers etc which depend on the versions of the libraries, the OS version and various library specific settings. Thus you need to provide all these information for better help. You might try to debug the issue yourself with tools like [SSLyze](https://github.com/nabla-c0d3/sslyze).

Comment: Apart from these information packet captures would be helpful and of course you should look at the log messages on the server side.

Comment: You could also try making a simple request (maybe even just an HTTP GET) to that URL with command-line curl, to see whether it gives you the same error or more debugging information.